# Placing datalabels at certain places of a graph in matplotlib python

Tags: list, function, matplotlib, dataset

The data set below plots a line graph and where the graphs line is blue on an incline and red on a decline. I want to add data labels to the points of change in color for the graph. I want to use the code below to add data labels to my current code. The data lables are meant to print out the x,y coordinate of the current position.

Code for adding data labels:

```
label = f"({x},{y})"   
plt.annotate(label, # this is the text
            (x,y), # this is the point to label
             textcoords="offset points", # how to position the text
             xytext=(0,10), # distance from text to points (x,y)
             ha='center') # horizontal alignment can be left, right or center
```

Current code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_long = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
L_Amount_list = [100.00, 9313.38, 43601.28, 61701.69, 74331.88, 198913.81, 153054.54, 119162.10, 74382.25, 203542.82, 160774.71, 220307.19, 366459.26]

colors = ['b' if a < b else 'r' for a,b in zip(L_Amount_list,L_Amount_list[1:])]      

for i in range(len(x_long)):
    try:
        plt.plot(x_long[i:i+2], L_Amount_list[i:i+2], color=colors[i])
    except:
        break
        
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is `except break` a good idea here? I'd add some fixed value like 0, or a hole. Also, I don't know much python, but the idea would be to track 2 values, and whenever there is a change blue to red or opposite, then you add the pair.

Comment: You are asking a new question, pasting [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65453559/changing-the-colour-based-on-the-graphs-positions-matplotlib/65457548#65457548) verbatim. I don't mind that you have a new issue and ask a question, but don't you need to have a reputation or acceptance of my answer?

Comment: Sorry  forgot to accept the answer, done it now